# rviz in ROS electric

Tags: rviz, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have recently installed ROS electric and found out that rviz comes with following error:

```
NODES
  /
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.101:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rviz-1]: started with pid [2976]
[ERROR] [1315474799.086848538]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot create GL vertex buffer in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::GLHardwareVertexBuffer at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.0/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 46)
^C[rviz-1] killing on exit
[rviz-1] escalating to SIGTERM
[rviz-1] escalating to SIGKILL
Shutdown errors:
 * process[rviz-1, pid 2976]: required SIGKILL. May still be running.
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

I wonder if anyone knows what is the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11148/rviz-in-ros-electric/) by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2011-09-11**:
I have Ubuntu 10.04, graphics card: nVidia Corporation G92 [GeForce 9800 GT], ros installed from .deb (synaptic). Furthermore, rviz has worked fine in cturtle and diamondback.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-08**:
To help you, we need a lot more information. What graphics hardware do you have? What OS version? X server settings? ROS installed from binary or source? Etc.?

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2011-09-08**:
The same happens to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need more information.  Can you please run rviz with the "-l" option to generate an Ogre.log file?  Like:

`rosrun rviz rviz -l`

This will cause rviz to generate an `Ogre.log` file.  When the Ogre 3D library has problems, it puts most of its useful output in Ogre.log (but only if you run with `-l`).

Also, see [the rviz troubleshooting page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting) for info on some common issues and a [guide to making useful bug reports](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting#reportingabug).

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far I have found 2 ways to get this failure:

- Run rviz remotely

Running rviz remotely is not supported.

- Have a misconfigured nvidia-OpenGL setup.

Having a misconfigured nvidia-OpenGL setup seems pretty easy.  I ran into that myself while trying to duplicate this error by reverting to an old driver version.  [This page](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/280.13/README/installedcomponents.html) was the seed that got me started on the fix.  Ultimately my problem was that rviz was linking against a version of libGL.so that did not match the driver.

I saw this by running

```
glxinfo | grep version
```

and seeing

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 270.41.06
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
```

So my installed OpenGL NVIDIA driver was version 270.41.06.

when i ran

```
roscd rviz
ldd bin/rviz | grep libGL
```

I saw this:

```
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f344c19e000)
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f344bf2c000)
libGLcore.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGLcore.so.1 (0x00007f34439dc000)
```

and then I ran

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
```

and saw

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 2011-09-14 09:59 libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.195.36.24
```

In other words, rviz was linking against a libGL from NVIDIA version 195.36.24.

To fix it, I just removed the offending library files:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libGL.so
sudo rm /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
sudo rm /usr/lib/libGL.so.195.36.24
```

The correct library files were already installed in the
`/usr/lib/nvidia-current` directory, and they were automatically found
when I ran rviz again.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on 2011-09-15**:
many thanks, it worked.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-09-14**:
It worked. Great!

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2011-09-14**:
:_) Worked great! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if it helps at this late date, but I just encountered this problem.  RViz worked in diamondback, but I got the segmentation fault in electric.  For me, first setting the OGRE_RTT_MODE to Copy as described here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting#Segfault_during_startup

and then removing my .rviz directory worked.  Note that neither one worked on their own, I had to do both to get it to start.

---

Originally posted by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) with karma: 280 on 2011-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1